# How best to fit many Spark ML models

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

(PySpark, either Spark 1.6 or 2.0, shared YARN cluster with dozens of nodes)

I'd like to run a bootstrapping analysis, with each boot strap sample running on a dataset that's too large to fit on a single executor.

The naive approach I was going to start with is:

- create spark dataframe of training dataset
- for i in (1,1000):

  - use df.sample() to create a sample_df
  - train the model (logistic classifier) on sample_df

Although each individual model is fit across the cluster, this doesn't seem to be very 'parallel' thinking.

Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: If you can spare some disk space you could generate all samples in a single pass, write to disk, and start separate Spark job on each subset. You'll be able to get much better resource utilization depending on job queues and avoid multiple shuffles after sampling. Of course if you depend hosted object store ignore this comment :)