# Tuning model fits in Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm fitting a large number of models in Pyspark via Spark ML (see: [How best to fit many Spark ML models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859520/how-best-to-fit-many-spark-ml-models?noredirect=1#comment72830065_42859520)) and I'm wondering what I can do to speed up individual fits.

My data set is a spark data frame that's approximately 50gb, read in from libsvm format, and I'm running on a dynamically allocated YARN cluster with allocated executor memory = 10gb. Fitting a logistic regression classifier, it creates about 30 steps of `treeAggregate at LogisticRegression.scala:1018`, with alternating shuffle reads and shuffle writes of ~340mb each.

Executors come and go but it seems like the typical stage runtime is about 5 seconds. Is there anything I can look at to improve performance on these fits?

Comment: See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19071

Answer (score 1):

As a general job in Spark, you can do some stuff to improve your training time.

**spark.driver.memory** look out for your driver memory, some algorithms do shuffle data to your driver (in order to reduce computing time), so it might be a source of enhancement or at least one point of failure to keep an eye at.

Change the **spark.executor.memory** so it uses the maximum needed by the job but it also uses as little as much so you can fit more executors in each node (machine) on the cluster, and as you have more workers, you'll have more computer power to handle the job.

**spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** since you probably use DataFrames to manipulate data, try different values on this parameter so that you can execute more tasks per executor.

**spark.executor.cores** use it below 5 and you're good, above that, you probably will increase the time an executor has to handle the "shuffle" of tasks inside of it.

**cache/persist**: try to persist your data before huge transformations, if you're afraid of your executors not being able to handle it use StorageLevel.DISK_AND_MEMORY, so you're able to use both.

**Important:** all of this is based on my own experience alone training algorithms using Spark ML over datasets with 1TB-5TB and 30-50 features, I've researched to improve my own jobs but I'm not qualified as a source of truth for your problem. Learn more about your data and watch the logs of your executors for further enhancements.